# NSIS script not able to find the file from Windir folder

Tags: nsis

> IfFileExists $windir\system32\drivers\pcitdrv.sys file_found file_not_found
>   
> file_found:
>   MessageBox MB_OK FileFound
>  
>   file_not_found:
>  
>   MessageBox MB_OK FileNotFound

This code always executing file_not_found portion of code even though the that file exists in respective path.

Also tried the below way:

Function AB
Var /GLOBAL OnlineOrOffline
${Locate} "$windir\system32\drivers\" "/L=F /M=pcitdrv.sys" "SetOnlineOfflineVarliable"
MessageBox MB_OK $OnlineOrOffline
FunctionEnd
Function SetOnlineOfflineVarliable
    StrCpy $R0 $R9
    StrCpy $OnlineOrOffline "Found"
    StrCpy $0 StopLocate
    Push $0
FunctionEnd

In this scenario also the callback function is not called.

Need help regarding this.

Or simply

My requirement is suppose a PC with $windir/system32/drivers/pcitdrv.sys file present and another PC is not having that file. During installation, there is a check for some license. Can we skip the license check based on the file presence?

Comment: Is this only happening on 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of the filesystem is [redirected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) when running on a 32-bit application on a 64-bit version of Windows.

$windir\system32 is redirected to $windir\SysWOW64.

You can turn off the redirection when performing the check:

```
!include x64.nsh
Section

${DisableX64FSRedirection}
StrCpy $0 ""
IfFileExists "$windir\system32\drivers\pcitdrv.sys" 0 +2
StrCpy $0 "1"
${EnableX64FSRedirection}

StrCmp $0 "" 0 file_found
MessageBox MB_OK FileNotFound
goto done
file_found:
MessageBox MB_OK FileFound
done:

SectionEnd
```

If you don't care about Windows XP 64-bit [support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589) you can use a special pseudo folder that always accesses the "real" system32 folder:

```
Section

IfFileExists "$windir\system32\drivers\pcitdrv.sys" file_found ; Check on 32-bit Windows
IfFileExists "$windir\sysnative\drivers\pcitdrv.sys" file_found ; Check on 64-bit Windows

MessageBox MB_OK FileNotFound
goto done
file_found:
MessageBox MB_OK FileFound
done:

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But what does that 0 +2 do. Also will this script work for all bit versions also? like 32/64 also

Comment: 0 is no jump, +2 is skip this and the next instruction. Should work everywhere.

Comment: Oh! Thank you Anders.

Answer (score 0):

One more doubt is actually 
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
StrCpy $0 ""
IfFileExists "$windir\system32\drivers\pcitdrv.sys" 0 +2
StrCpy $0 "1"
${EnableX64FSRedirection}
StrCmp $0 "" 0 file_found
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
StrCpy $0 ""
IfFileExists "$windir\system32\drivers\tcitdrv.sys" 0 +2
StrCpy $0 "1"
${EnableX64FSRedirection}
StrCmp $0 "" 0 file_found
goto done
file_found:

done:
I would like to check two files pcit and tcit.
Is this correct?