# NSIS FIleExists in C:\Windows\System32\

Tags: nsis

I am trying to check with NSIS if a DLL exists in the folder "C:\Windows\System32".

Unfortunately the check always returns false.

Is the folder protected by admin privileges?
The installation script has no admin privileges and I want to keep it that way.

Is there any way I can still check if this file exists?

Here is the code:

```
Function DetectDLL
  ${If} ${FileExists} "C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140_1.dll"
      MessageBox MB_OK "File found."
  ${Else}
      MessageBox MB_OK "File not found."
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

I have tried [IfFileExists](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/IfFileExists) as well.
Here I got the same result.

[I also tried ${DisableX64FSRedirection}.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113285/nsis-script-not-able-to-find-the-file-from-windir-folder)
Unfortunately I can't compile the installer in this case.

> Invalid command: "${DisableX64FSRedirection}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows will secretly access `%windir%\SysWow64\xyz` when you ask for `%windir%\System32\xyz`.

Just add `!include x64.nsh` before using `${DisableX64FSRedirection}`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
That has solved my problem.